# UBUNTU specific problem--(16.04)--Chrome 'ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE'

Tags: networking, dns

bI have been running dual boot UBUNTU 16.04 and Windows 7 for months. I recently asked software updater to do routine update and then rebooted. Afterwards, both chrome(ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE) and firefox(Server not found) began giving errors for network sites not 'SECURE'. The problem is in Ubuntu only, in Windows, both browsers still work perfectly. Two specific sites I have used are 'news.google.com' and 'match.com'. Also 'apt-get update' cannot access all of the software sites. I don't know enough to find the problem. Please help.

```
jmb@jmb:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
    # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback
jmb@jmb:~$ sudo service networking restart
[sudo] password for jmb: 
jmb@jmb:~$
```

output with wired ethernet

```
jmb@jmb:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:f7:28:e1:7b:4e  
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4500:574b:186f:5771:d777:1766/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::6d87:6d17:7156:1643/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4500:574b::ffd6/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4500:574b:a46b:c8f5:9bcb:8703/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:103 errors:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:10056 (10.0 KB)  TX bytes:14021 (14.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1411 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1411 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:114036 (114.0 KB)  TX bytes:114036 (114.0 KB)
```

output for wireless

```
jmb@jmb:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:f7:28:e1:7b:4e  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1649 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1649 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:150581 (150.5 KB)  TX bytes:150581 (150.5 KB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d8:5d:e2:64:83:03  
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4500:574b:8803:1bd:cdb0:3a91/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4500:574b::7c0b/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::c79:68f8:ae1f:4168/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3012 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2730 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1969317 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:541691 (541.6 KB)

jmb@jmb:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp4s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"BISHOP"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 5C:8F:E0:5E:5A:3C   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=59/70  Signal level=-51 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:7   Missed beacon:0

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

jmb@jmb:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for jmb: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 10
       serial: 68:f7:28:e1:7b:4e
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0a04000-f0a04fff memory:f0a00000-f0a03fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: d8:5d:e2:64:83:03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723be driverversion=4.8.0-58-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:49 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:f0800000-f0803fff

jmb@jmb:~$ dkms status
jmb@jmb:~$
```

here is wired ifconfig today

```
jmb@jmb:~$ ifconfig
enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:f7:28:e1:7b:4e  
          inet addr:10.0.0.129  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4500:574b:758e:b886:578d:f23e/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::6d87:6d17:7156:1643/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4500:574b::ffd6/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2601:681:4500:574b:a46b:c8f5:9bcb:8703/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:67242 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:28635 errors:0 dropped:47 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:90905501 (90.9 MB)  TX bytes:5601688 (5.6 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3638 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3638 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:338836 (338.8 KB)  TX bytes:338836 (338.8 KB)
```

Comment: did the kernel update?  if yes, you'll need new drivers. or if you have source, recompile them for the new kernel

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and please format your code properly. Also add output of `sudo service networking restart` maybe the problem is the known issue of the namespace change for NICs from e.g. eth0 to ens3

Comment: jmb@jmb:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
jmb@jmb:~$ sudo service networking restart
[sudo] password for jmb: 
jmb@jmb:~$

Comment: will any of this help?

Comment: this comment space is very restrictive--as I said previous 'news,google.com' has no error; 'match.com' gives error. I tried to include 'wget' for both and 'apt-get update' but there was no room for all of output

Comment: You're not getting an IPv4 address. What happens if you use a wired connection instead of wireless? Do so, and show me ifconfig again. Ping me at `@heynnema`. Report back.

Comment: jmb@jmb:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) auto lo iface lo inet loopback jmb@jmb:~$ sudo service networking restart [sudo] password for jmb: jmb@jmb:~$

Comment: @derHugo  how do I get enough space to add the output?

Comment: @derHugo  how do I format code properly? Sorry

Comment: @heynnema  I think that I am making a mess here..

Comment: Why do you think that you're making a mess? I made a small mistake. I reviewed your original question, and I see that you showed the ifconfig for a **wired** connection. I should have asked if you have a wireless network that you can connect to, and then show `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`. Tell me how your wired network is connected together... does the cable from the computer connects to what... a router... or the dsl/cable modem?

Comment: ps: In addition to the above questions, please also show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `dkms status`.

Comment: @b-jakki u can post the output in your question. and comment here to see the updated question :)

Comment: @heynnema  you made no mistake..I had too many links in original post and couldn't add to question, so I deleted some..I normally run wireless..when I hooked wired, it was directly into the router

Comment: @tgkprog  thank you, I'm getting the hang of it

Comment: @heyenna  my mistake..ethernet hooks to cable modem, thanks

Comment: You're not getting an IPv4 address in wired or wireless mode. Something must have gone wrong with the updates. Assuming that it all worked before the updates, and you haven't manually edited some network configuration, I'd reinstall Ubuntu. Use a 16.04.2 DVD/USB.

Comment: @heynnema  I must not have waited for connection to update when I previously hooked direct..I just tried again and when hooked direct with ethernet, all browsers work perfectly..but still problem when wireless..new output added

Comment: @heynnema  I ran live from USB and had the same problems as before with wireless, thanks

Comment: OK, progress. It works fine with a wired connection, but not with a wireless connection, yes? Try a different wireless network connection to make sure it's not a problem with your router/modem. Look for `inet addr:` in the `iwconfig`. Also check the IPv4 tab of the wireless network config for the wireless network that you're connecting to, and confirm that the settings are correct.

Comment: @heynnema Hooking direct with ethernet cable fixed whatever the problem was and everything is working correctly again, thanks

Comment: @derHugo As part of trouble shooting we hooked computer direct to modem with ethernet cable..everything worked with direct hook and continues to work after reboot, thanks

Comment: I thought that we still had a wireless issue? A working wired connection is no big surprise... although it took us a long time to get there.